# Pandas column redefinition (extension) does not work

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have two data frames (let say `A` and `B`) indexed with dates.

I define a column in `B` as following

```
B["column1"] = A.shift(1)
```

Later, when I add additional data to `A` and I want to update `B`, it doesn't work.

`B["column1] = A.shift(1)` still produces the same data before I added additional data to `A`.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: If you add a minimum working example with code and data, that would help.

Comment: Not a `machine-learning` or `numpy` question, kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: reindex B with the updated index of A ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perform a [`df.reindex()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html)  before your assignment statement, as follows:

```
B = B.reindex(A.index)
```

Then, you can get your desired result with your code:

```
B["column1"] = A.shift(1)
```

**Caution:**  If your dataframe B has other columns with values built with date indices other than the indices of dataframe A, reindexing in this way may cause loss of data in other columns of dataframe B.  To overcome this, you can reindex B to the *combined index of A and B* with a `union()` function as follows:

```
B = B.reindex(A.index.union(B.index))
```

### Demo Run

```
A_index = pd.date_range(start='2021/1/1', periods=8)
A = pd.Series([10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80], index=A_index)
print(A)

2021-01-01    10
2021-01-02    20
2021-01-03    30
2021-01-04    40
2021-01-05    50
2021-01-06    60
2021-01-07    70
2021-01-08    80
Freq: D, dtype: int64

B = pd.DataFrame()
B["column1"] = A.shift(1)
print(B)

            column1
2021-01-01      NaN
2021-01-02     10.0
2021-01-03     20.0
2021-01-04     30.0
2021-01-05     40.0
2021-01-06     50.0
2021-01-07     60.0
2021-01-08     70.0

#  Add data to A
A = A.append(pd.Series([100, 110, 120], index=pd.date_range(start='2021/1/21', periods=3)))
print(A)

2021-01-01     10
2021-01-02     20
2021-01-03     30
2021-01-04     40
2021-01-05     50
2021-01-06     60
2021-01-07     70
2021-01-08     80
2021-01-21    100             <= New data
2021-01-22    110             <= New data
2021-01-23    120             <= New data
dtype: int64

#Run new code
B = B.reindex(A.index)

#Run existing code
B["column1"] = A.shift(1)

print(B)

            column1
2021-01-01      NaN
2021-01-02     10.0
2021-01-03     20.0
2021-01-04     30.0
2021-01-05     40.0
2021-01-06     50.0
2021-01-07     60.0
2021-01-08     70.0
2021-01-21     80.0             <= New data
2021-01-22    100.0             <= New data
2021-01-23    110.0             <= New data
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use `DataFrame.at`

```
B.at["column1"] = A.shift(1)
```

reference [DataFrame.at](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at.html)